# automatic creation of folder from the file name

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a folder containing many files named as such:

```
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191121130102.txt.xml.done 
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191121131102.txt.xml.done
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191122133102.txt.xml.done    
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191123132102.txt.xml.done
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_LOCK_20191123132102.txt.xml.done
sale_jone_BAL_EXT_LOCK_20191123132102.txt.xml.done
```

I want to create folder with name (bound-2019-11-21) from the file name given above. In the files, the first 8 integers are the date.

How can I accomplish this?
here i am having a folder of 
HOPE
LOCK

now what i want is to creat folder in HOPE from the file name
eg
HOPE-->bound-2019-11-21

This is my code:

```
path='../picture/jack' #this is the path of folder in which the files are 
                        located
dirs=os.listdir(path)
b=[]
for file in dirs:
    #print(file)
    a=re.findall(r'HOPE',file) #finding the file name HOPE from the folder
    if a:
      b.append(file)

print(b)
for i in b:
    t=re.findall(r'\d{8}',i) #finding the date from the file in list
    print(t)
```

Comment: What have you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want to create 1 folder or as many as your files?

Comment: the folder should be create depending on dates

Comment: I notice in your example you only appear to be trying to make directories for files with `HOPE` in them but that wasn't mentioned in your spec. Is that correct, or do you want directories for `LOCK` as well? Should the files be moved into these directories once they're created? You'll need to be very clear with your requirements if you'd like a helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: shorter `if 'HOPE' in file:`. If filenames have the same construction then you could use slicing to get data - `"sale_jone_BAL_EXT_LOCK_20191123132102.txt.xml.done"[-27:-19]` -> `20191123`

Comment: if you have string `date = "20191123"` then you can slice it to create folder name `name = 'bound-{}-{}-{}'.format(date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])` and then `os.makedirs(name)` or `os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, name))`

Comment: Just iterate in your `os.listdir()` and split the file name strings at "HOPE_" and go forward n characters. Then open a new folder with that name using the `os.mkdir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format has some variability to it and/or you have a mix of files in the directory, some of which you need to ignore, regex is a reasonable choice. `\w+?(\d{8,})\.txt\.xml\.done$` seems like a good starting approach since we only have word characters, a batch of at least 8 digits, and the `.txt.xml.done` suffix.

```
import os
import re

path = "../picture/jack"
path = os.path.join(*path.split("/"))

for f in os.listdir(path):
    date = re.match(r"\w+?(\d{8,})\.txt\.xml\.done$", f)

    if date:
        p = r"(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d).*"
        dest = os.path.join(path, re.sub(p, r"\1-\2-\3", date.group(1)))
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
        os.replace(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(dest, f))
```

This will create and move files in folders according to the yyyy-mm-dd format.

You can use `"\w*?_HOPE_\w*?(\d{8,})\.txt\.xml\.done$"`
 if you only want files containing `_HOPE_` as in your example code.

Comment: folder name is coming wrong it is coming like 0191-12-11 I want 2019-12-11

Comment: I don't see how that's possible based on the data you gave. Are your filenames identical to the ones above? [Run it here and see](https://repl.it/repls/CriminalPureTriangle).

Comment: here it is working great in my it is not working why it is so?

Comment: I'm not sure. If your files are the same, try printing the `date.group(1)` and `folder` variables? What OS are you running? Again, I'd check that the file names are as you posted above.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191121130102.txt.xml.done' -> '../Inbound(2)/Inbound\\2019-11-21\\sale_jone_BAL_EXT_HOPE_20191121130102.txt.xml.done'
this error i am getting                                                                                                i am using windows 10

Comment: Looks like a typical path problem. Are you using `os.path.join` on your base `path`? I'll check it out on my Win 10 and see if I can help figure it out.

Comment: All right, I tried it out and the problem was the path for `os.replace` was assuming `.` as the source directory. I also used `os.path.join` to make sure the path is portable. Does the updated code work for you?

Comment: OK, fixed. The problem is I wasn't using a lazy quantifier so `\w` character class was gobbling up everything but the last 8 digits. Sorry about that and glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

If all of your filenames are similar then you can `slice` it.

```
date = filename[-27:-19]
```

or you can use `split()`

```
date = filename.split('_')[-1][:8]
```

and then you can slice date to create new name

```
name = 'bound-{}-{}-{}'.format(date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])
```

and you can create folder

```
os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, name), exist_ok=True)
```

With argument `exist_ok=True` it will not raise error if folder exists.

**EDIT**: You have [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) which can move to new place. There is also [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) which in background uses `os. rename`

---

```
import os
path = '../picture/jack'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if 'HOPE' in filename:

        date = filename[-27:-19]
        #date = filename.split('_')[-1][:8]
        name = 'bound-{}-{}-{}'.format(date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])

        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, name), exist_ok=True)

        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(name, filename))
        #shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(name, filename))
```

Comment: i want to move the file of name HOPE in the created folder how can it possible i am new to programming  thanks

Comment: you have [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) which can move to new place. There is also [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) which in background uses `os. rename`